# Flat (2D) mesh of silver threads to reflect electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

I have only basic knowledge in physics from school and I am struggling to find an answer:
Can a blanket with a worked-in mesh of silver threads really reflect electromagnetic field from mobiles and/or WLAN in order to shield a human sleeping underneath? I always thought a faraday cage would have to enclose the shielded object from all sides.
So maybe this blanket would work as an antenna in the contrary and make things worse?
And would it make a difference if there was a second blanket underneath the body? Then it would be more similar to a "cage".

Comment: Please remove the word  "protect" .  There is no injury risk in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The 'rule of thumb' is that a metal mesh with open spaces of dimension X will block wavelengths  greater than  X/2  (you can argue about it being X or X/4 but this is close enough).   That's how/why the screen dimensions on a microwave oven door are designed.

Yes, WLAN, as well as satellite TV signals,  FM radio signals,  4G cellular signals, and a few dozen other EM-radiation sources are entering your putative "person in bed" from all angles, so if you want to block off all signals you'd need to complete the "Faraday cage".

However, there is no medical justification for such actions.